# Mongodb - storing boundary boxes geojson

Tags: mongodb

I know I can store points like this

```
location: {
      type: "Point",
      coordinates: [-73.856077, 40.848447]
}
```

but how do I store data like

```
{"boundingbox":["-55.3228175","-9.0880125","72.2461932","168.2261259"]}
```

I want to be able do something like

```
location: {
      type: "Polygon",
      coordinates: ["-55.3228175","-9.0880125","72.2461932","168.2261259"]
}
```

But that won't work.

I need to be able to use it later on.

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend you to read the GeoJson documentation https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/geojson/

In fact, a polygon coordinate should be an array of arrays of coordinates

[[[cordA, cordB]]]

Remember one thing, when you are trying to map a polygon you should start and finish with the same coordinate to close the polygon. Also, the right shape for polygons is the next one:

```
{
  type: "Polygon",
  coordinates: [ [ [ 0 , 0 ] , [ 3 , 6 ] , [ 6 , 1 ] , [ 0 , 0  ] ] ]
}
```

Your current object has the coordinates as strings, which should be the first thing you need to fix.